# Text invisible yet appearing in inspector

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

My last question was answered so quickly and smoothly I thought I'd return with another issue I'm failing to figure out on my own.

I used one of the examples to create this graph:

```
data = [{ "label": "1", "value": 20 },
        { "label": "2", "value": 50 },
        { "label": "3", "value": 30 },
        { "label": "4", "value": 45 }];

var width = 400,
    height = 450;

var outerRadius = 200,
    innerRadius = outerRadius / 3,
    color = d3.scale.category20c();

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
    .value(function (d) { return d.value; });

var pieData = pie(data);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(innerRadius);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + (outerRadius + 50) + ")");

svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", -(outerRadius + 10))
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Title[enter image description here][1]");

svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(pieData)
  .enter().append("path")
    .each(function (d) { d.outerRadius = outerRadius - 20; })
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("fill", function (d, i) { return color(i); })
    .on("mouseover", arcTween(outerRadius, 0))
    .on("mouseout", arcTween(outerRadius - 20, 150));

svg.selectAll("path")
     .append("text")
     .attr("transform", function (d) {
         d.innerRadius = 0;
         d.outerRadius = outerRadius;
         return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
     })
     .attr("fill", "white")
     .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
     .text(function (d, i) { return data[i].label; });


function arcTween(outerRadius, delay) {
    return function () {
        d3.select(this).transition().delay(delay).attrTween("d", function (d) {
            var i = d3.interpolate(d.outerRadius, outerRadius);
            return function (t) { d.outerRadius = i(t); return arc(d); };
        });
    };
}
```

The idea being that when you hover over a section on the pie chart (donut chart?) it expands. However, this made my labels dissapear and I can't manage to make them come back. I either get an error, or they just don't show up on the screen (even though I see the tag in the inspector). Any obvious thing I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: @Carcigenicate As the code is in JS, I assume yes x)

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes I did, I apologize. I'll see if I can fix that tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **cannot** append a `<text>` element to a `<path>` element. It simply doesn't work in an SVG.  Even not working, the `<text>` element will be appended.

That being said, a solution is creating a new "enter" selection for the texts:

```
svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(pieData)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
        d.innerRadius = 0;
        d.outerRadius = outerRadius;
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
    })
    .attr("fill", "white")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d, i) {
        return data[i].label;
    });
```

Here is your updated code:

```js
data = [{
  "label": "1",
  "value": 20
}, {
  "label": "2",
  "value": 50
}, {
  "label": "3",
  "value": 30
}, {
  "label": "4",
  "value": 45
}];

var width = 400,
  height = 450;

var outerRadius = 200,
  innerRadius = outerRadius / 3,
  color = d3.scale.category20c();

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });

var pieData = pie(data);

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(innerRadius);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + (outerRadius + 50) + ")");

svg.append("text")
  .attr("x", 0)
  .attr("y", -(outerRadius + 10))
  .style("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text("Title[enter image description here][1]");

svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(pieData)
  .enter().append("path")
  .each(function(d) {
    d.outerRadius = outerRadius - 20;
  })
  .attr("d", arc)
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return color(i);
  })
  .on("mouseover", arcTween(outerRadius, 0))
  .on("mouseout", arcTween(outerRadius - 20, 150));

svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(pieData)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    d.innerRadius = 0;
    d.outerRadius = outerRadius;
    return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
  })
  .attr("fill", "white")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .text(function(d, i) {
    return data[i].label;
  });


function arcTween(outerRadius, delay) {
  return function() {
    d3.select(this).transition().delay(delay).attrTween("d", function(d) {
      var i = d3.interpolate(d.outerRadius, outerRadius);
      return function(t) {
        d.outerRadius = i(t);
        return arc(d);
      };
    });
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```